# How to set a constant value inside an array of structures?

Tags: c, arrays, structure

```
typedef struct all{
  int x;
  int ast[5];
}ALL;

ALL x[5];

int main(void){
  ALL y[5];
  // ...
}
```

How will I be able to set a constant value to `ast[5]` so that all array variables will have the same value of `ast[]`?

Comment: why? is there no other way to do that?

Comment: The language simply can't express it (yet).

Comment: Write a function to initialize your array and call it for each declaration. But it relies on the programmer's discipline - there's no way to enforce the initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming from the tags that the question is for C and not C++.

You could have a function that takes the size of the struct array and returns a pointer to the start of the array, like this:

```
typedef struct my_struct{
    int i;
    int var[5];
} my_struct;

my_struct* init_my_struct(int size){
    my_struct *ptr = malloc(size * sizeof(struct));
    for(my_struct *i = ptr; (i - ptr) < size; i++)
        i->var = // whatever value you want to assign to it
            // or copy a static value to the the array element
}
```

Now you can use it in your code in this way:

```
my_struct *my_struct_ptr = init_my_struct(5); // values inited as required
```

The drawbacks of this approach are that you are moving from declaring an array to using memory on the heap.
Also, you cannot keep someone from creating an array of a certain size and using it with values being assigned to it the way you would want.

Comment: please upvote or accept answers to your question to encourage answering and for the benefit of other looking for answers to the same question... :-)

Comment: Won't the initial value of `i` (`my_struct *i = 0`) mean that `i->var = ...;` is trying to dereference `NULL`? You probably want something more like `for (my_struct *i = ptr; i < ptr + size; i++)`. Or just use an integer as the loop variable, so you can do `ptr[i]->var`.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct all {
  int x;
  int ast[5];
} ALL;

ALL x[5];
ALL constast = {0, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};

int main(void) {
  ALL y[5] = {[0] = constast, [1] = constast, [2] = constast,
              [3] = constast, [4] = constast};
  // ...
}
```

Comment: assign the random numebrs inside `main()`, before using the variable for other initializations... but then they're not "constant values".